# Undefined reference to function in linux makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, fltk

I have a problem with make compiling on linux.... getting error about undefined reference.
Briefly, we use FLUID, a GUI designer. The codes from FLUID are inside the class MyProjectGUI. I wrote a callback function outside of FLUID, which is called from within functions of MyProjectGUI.

**MyProjectGUI.h** has include to callback function header:
`#include "students/stu_callbacks.h"`
**MyProjectGUI.cxx**:

```
#include "MyProjectGUI.h"
....
void MyProjectGUI::somecallback_i([args])
{   ...
   brandNewCallback();
    ...
}
```

In "students/**stu_callbacks.h**":

```
#include "../main_utils.h"
void brandNewCallback();
```

Then in "students/**stu_callbacks.cpp**":

```
#include "stu_callbacks.h"
void brandNewCallback() 
{  ...stuffs...
}
```

**Makefile** I used:

```
VXLDIR = [....]

CFLAGS = [...VXL header paths...] -Wno-deprecated -DJPEG_LIB_VERSION=80

CC = g++

#fltk library paths and libraries
FLTKLDFLAGS = -L/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -Wl,-rpath,/local/lib -lfltk_gl -lGLU -lGL -lfltk -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lpthread -lm -lXext -lX11 -lsupc++

#vxl library paths and libraries
VXLLDFLAGS = -L$(VXLDIR)/bin/lib -lvil -lvnl_algo -lvnl_io -lvnl -lv3p_netlib -lvcl -lvul -lpng -ltiff -lopenjpeg2 -lgeotiff
LDFLAGS = -lstdc++ $(FLTKLDFLAGS) $(VXLLDFLAGS)

FLUID = fluid

%.o: %.cxx
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.cxx: %.fl
    $(FLUID) -c $<

BASIC_OBJ   = gl/glutils.o gl/Texture.o main.o file/load_image.o

IMDRAW_OBJ  = [...imdraw...]

UI_OBJ      = MyProjectUI.o

UI_CPP      = MyProjectUI.cxx MyProjectUI.h

GRAPHIC_OBJ = graphics/graphics.o

STUDENT_OBJ = graphics/graphics_algorithm.o

imdraw-code/myproject:  $(UI_CPP) $(BASIC_OBJ) $(UI_OBJ) $(STUDENT_OBJ) $(GRAPHIC_OBJ) $(IMDRAW_OBJ)

    $(CC) -o ../bin/viscomp $(BASIC_OBJ) $(UI_OBJ) $(GRAPHIC_OBJ) $(IMDRAW_OBJ) $(STUDENT_OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)
```

- Compiling with this Makefile under Linux at university gets error about undefined reference to function "brandNewCallback()", from MyProjectGUI.cxx. Note it did NOT complain about not finding "students/stu_callbacks.h", so the header should be read.
- The exact same code compiled without issue using Visual Studio.
- The structure of this is similar to that "file/load_image" listed in the Makefile, ("load_image" function is called from within MyProjectGUI, the includes are setup very similarly)... yet that one doesn't cause any issue.
- Tried adding "students/stu_callbacks.o" to "STUDENT_OBJ in Makefile, then I got fatal errors about not finding the includes within the "main_utils.h" include of stud_callbacks.h, which doesn't make sense at all. Other files source "main_utils.h" without issue.
- Tried calling the func as `::brandNewCallback();`, still same error.
- The immediate workaround is to put all this callback code within MyProjectGUI...

I don't get how I can't get this to work as it, and it bugs the hack out of me. I already spent 5+hours last night trying/googling... so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see you listing `students/stu_callbacks.cpp` or its object file anywhere in the makefile.

Comment: By the way, you should probably not list header files among the source files (I'm thinking about the `MyProjectUI.h` file in `UI_CPP`).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, I tried that, see bullet point #4. Not familiar with makefile at all tho. We were only told to put additional codes under "student/", and compile with the provided Makefile. There isn't even mention of the need to modify Makefile. But then I modified it and still getting errors as mentioned in the bullet point. As for UI_CPP... that looks strange to me too, but it's the provided Makefile... at least it does compile before I added in my callbacks stuffs.

Comment: Is this a compile or link error? The header is only relevant for the compile step. An undefined reference error during linking means you aren't including the build library in your link line. (Which would appear to be what you were trying to fix with bullet 4 but that apparently ran into other errors?)

Comment: @Etan Reisner, I think it's compile error?!.. it's something like "MyProjectUI.cxx (0x188): undefined reference to function brandNewCallback(...) ..."

Comment: The exact error would probably be helpful. As would the command that is being run when the error occurs.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: Yes this is an assignment, but fiddling with Makefile isn't the purpose, and as I mentioned, I can workaround this by putting the callback code inside the UI. I just want to know why it fails as it :)

Comment: @Etan Reisner  Ok nvm, looks more like linker error. From http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/debugging/errors/, in the form of "somefile.o(address): undefined reference to `Foo(void)'". The error happened during MyProjectUI.o with undefined brandNewCallback(void). Sorry can't post the exact command/error now as my workplace blocks off ssh to my university server apparently..

Answer (score 1):

Your rule `%.o: %.cxx` instructs Make how to compile source files with extension `.cxx`. However, your
own C++ source file is `students/stu_callbacks.cpp`. You did not provide rule to make object file(s) out of .cpp files, or to make object file out of the students/stu_callbacks.cpp file. Therefore, your stu_callbacks were not linked in, and naturally linker complains.

The problem with header file is similar - C++ compiler probably does not have include path set.